# liftM vs. raw replicate

Tags: haskell, ghc

```
replicate 3 "hi"
```

produces

```
["hi", "hi", "hi"]
```

but

```
liftM (replicate 3) "hi"
```

produces

```
["hhh", "iii"]
```

How the `liftM` operates (precisely)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summary: `liftM = map`.

---

The `liftM` function has type `Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`. That is, it takes a function and something in a monad and applies the function "through" the monad. (Or, to look at it another way, it has type `Monad m => (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)`, i.e. it converts a function into one that operates through a monad.)

In this case we have `liftM (replicate 3) ['h','i']` (remember that `"hi"` is just shorthand for a list of the individual characters), so the monad in question is the list monad. The definition of `liftM` for lists is equivalent to `map` (the two functions have the same type, which is a big hint.) Thus:

```
liftM (replicate 3) ['h','i'] = map (replicate 3) ['h','i']
     = [replicate 3 'h', replicate 3 'i'] = ["hhh","iii"]
```

Answer (score 7):

The `liftM` function is another name for `fmap`<sup>*</sup>, which is equivalent to `map` when it operates on lists.

```
liftM (replicate 3) "hi"
  = [replicate 3 x | x <- "hi"]
  = [replicate 3 'h', replicate 3 'i']
  = ["hhh", "iii"]
```

#### Footnotes

<sup>*</sup> The difference between `liftM` and `fmap` is the different class context, since due to historical reasons, `Monad` does not imply `Functor`.